# Deviation of the set $M$ from the set $N$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Suppose both $M \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $N \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are nonempty, compact and convex sets.

We define $d(.,.)$ and $h^{+}(.,.)$ by

- $d ( M  , N ):= \sup_{g \in M} \, \, \inf_{h \in  N} \, \| g - h \|  $
- $h^{+}(M, N):=\inf \left\{\varepsilon>0: N + B_{\varepsilon}(0)  \supset M \right\}$

---

**Does the following hold:**

$$
d ( M  , N ) = h^{+}(M, N) \;?
$$

---

**My thoughts:**

I think this is true, but I am not absolutely sure.

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both $N$ and $M$ non-empty (if $M$ is empty then $d(M, N) = -\infty$ and $h^+(M, N) = 0$ and if $N$ is empty but $M$ isn't then $d(M, N) = h^+(M, N) = \infty$), we can choose $g \in M$ s.t. $\inf_{h \in N} \|g - h\| > d(M, N) - \varepsilon$. Can it be possible that $g \in N + B_{\varepsilon / 2}$?

For the other direction $M \subset N + B_{h^+(M, N) + \varepsilon}$. Can nearest point in $N$ to $g \in M$ be farther away from $g$ than $h^+(M, N) + \varepsilon$?

Comment: So you mean, that the above statement is true?

Comment: Yes, it's true (assuming non-emptiness).

Comment: Many thanks for your effort :)